# Catching a Diamond Of Death Exception (boost::system::system_error and std::system_error)

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, boost, boost-system

I have a library, and I wish to leverage the design of [boost::system::system_error](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/system/doc/html/system.html#ref_system_error).  C++ adopted this design in 2011 with [std::system_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error).  I would like for client code to have the option of working with Boost exceptions or with Standard exceptions.  Therefore, when my library code needs to communicate an error, I throw my own exception type that inherits from `boost::system::system_error` *and* `std::system_error`:

```
class my_exception : public std::system_error, public boost::system::system_error {
  // implementation
};
```

Unfortunately, this is a [Deadly Diamond of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) with respect to the common base class `std::runtime_error`.  Nonetheless, client code is able to catch these exceptions as either `std::system_error` or as `boost::system::system_error`:

```
try {
  a_function_that_might_throw_my_exception();
} catch (const std::system_error& ex) {
  // Works as intended - correctly catches a reference to the `my_exception` object
}

try {
  a_function_that_might_throw_my_exception();
} catch (const boost::system::system_error& ex) {
  // Also works
}
```

However, an expression of type `my_exception` cannot bind to a reference to `std::runtime_error` (or it's base class, `std::exception`), due to the ambiguity of the diamond: should it bind to `std::system_error`'s base class object, or should it bind to `boost::system::system_error`'s base class object?  The result is that the thrown object is not caught at all:

```
try {
  a_function_that_might_throw_my_exception();
} catch (const std::runtime_error& ex) {
  // Doesn't catch here!
} catch (...) {
  std::printf("Sadness\n");
}
```

[Godbolt demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/PfT9MhGPd)

**The main question:** Is there a way to communicate to the compiler which base class subobject shoud be preferred when binding a deadly-diamond-type to a reference-to-base?  In normal code you could `static_cast<const std::runtime_error&>(ex)` or `static_cast<const boost::system::system_error&>(ex)`, but I can't write a `static_cast` into the compiler's magical exception-handling code.

**Secondary question:** Is there a better way make my code interoperable with both `std::` and `boost::system::` error handling?

**EDIT**:
The problem is that some library code uses both `boost::` and `std::` APIs under the hood; I therefore don't necessarily always have the option to throw my choice of `boost::system::system_error` or `std::system_error`.

Comment: seems like a bad idea to me, just throw one or the other and document which one that is. You could even have a compiler flag to switch between them

Comment: Personally I would handle this as a compile time option.  Have an alias like `using exception_base = EXCEPTION_BASE_TO_USE` and then have `#ifndef USE_BOOST_EXCEPTIONS #then #define EXCEPTION_BASE_TO_USE std::exception #else #define EXCEPTION_BASE_TO_USE boost::exception`

Comment: What's your goal with supporting `boost::system_error`? I wouldn't even add a macro switch. Any sane user code would already catch both `std::system_error` *and* `boost::system_error`, if that part of the boost is used in the project, I think?

Comment: I supposed the idea is that, while not *officially* standard, some aspects of Boost are *de-facto* standard (especially Boost.ASIO and any parts of Boost that ASIO depends on, including Boost.System).  Having to deal with two parallel and almost identical APIs for error handling is obnoxious - I have an elegant(ish) approach for allowing client code to use their choice of `error_code`; I was trying to do the same for `system_error`.

Comment: I would consider this a defect in the standard (and in boost). All inheritance within the exception hierarchy should be `virtual`, to avoid this sort of problem (which was very frequent when the standard was initially introduced). Not that that helps you in any way.

Comment: @JamesKanze And it can't be fixed without an ABI break.  Alternative would be a language change introducing a new syntax to specify which base class sub-object should be preferred in ambiguous situations.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm shocked boost didn't already `virtual` inherit actually. I thought I learned to do that *from* Boost's code in the past. It might have been Marshall Clow's C++FQA then

Comment: @SumDood That wouldn't solve the problem in general. Usually, you really need only a single instance. Of course, `boost` could solve the problem by making `boost::system_error` derive from `std::system_error`, or even making it just a `typedef` for `std::system_error` (conditional on the version of C++ being modern enough to have `std::system_error` -- the reason there is a `boost::system_error` is that at the time, there wasn't a `std::system_error`).

Comment: @JamesKanze Interesting thought about having `boost::system::system_error` inherit from `std::system_error` or having it be a `typedef`, although I would anticipate resistance to such a change since the behavior of lots of code that `catch`es both exception types from the same `try` block would change.

I think the solution is to document that both could be thrown, and to use `std::sysem_error` exclusively to communicate my library's errors - client code will just have to deal with it.